# How to fix the size of a cell when the text inside increment size?

Tags: html, size, html-table

I've this

```
<table id="buttons">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px; height:100px;" OnClick="return goToDispPage();"> 
                    <p style="font-size: 50px"><b>D</b></p>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td OnClick="return goToGestioneComm();">
                <b>C</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

But the dimension of the first  change if i change the size of the

inside the .
It's possible to avoid this??

Comment: Size of the ___ inside the ___? And can you post your JavaScript code, assuming the changes are referring to what you're doing in your functions?

Comment: the javascript its not related to this. I just need a big letter inside a square cell.